# How to use an organization domain with google api in our spring boot oauth2 web application?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-console

I tried below code in application.properties file but didn't work

```
 spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.my-oauth-provider.authorization-  uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?hd=domain.com
```

I refered https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect but couldn't find how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method that is from the google api console we can give application type as internal in oauth consent screen.

[you can see from below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S9CN.png)